# Fix 'Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$vuetify.breakpoint is undefined' in Vue 2 for 'vuetify-file-browser' module

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm new to Vuejs and  started a project in which I want to display a file explorer in the browser.

I am using a module called 'vuetify-file-browser' as it has a large amount of the required logic, however I am struggling to get it to display in the browser, errors included below, my source is then below that. Also, vuetify-file-browser requires Vuetify 2 to run as Vue 3 has no compatible Vuetify version that suits the component, so I cannot change the project to Vue 3. If the best solution is using another module I'm open to that.

**Things I have tried**:

- Research the errors and console log
- Change webpack version from 4 to 5 and back again
- npm uninstall, followed by npm install
- Complete reinstall of node_modules
- Vue.use(Vuetify) in main.js
- Adding loader to webpack.config.js using fibers to handle both sass and scss files
- Changing from node-sass to sass

The error message is received in Firefox devtools console, but the project itself deploys fine, displaying nothing but an empty FileBrowser element (nothing visible).

**Error log**

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$vuetify.breakpoint is undefined"

found in

---> <FileBrowser> at node_modules/vuetify-file-browser/src/FileBrowser.vue
       <FileBrowser> at src/components/FileBrowser.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> vue.esm.js:628
---------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: _vm.$vuetify.breakpoint is undefined
    render FileBrowser.vue:31
    VueJS 45
    <anonymous> main.js:8
    js build.js:8912
    __webpack_require__ build.js:790
    fn build.js:101
    0 build.js:8937
    __webpack_require__ build.js:790
    <anonymous> build.js:857
    <anonymous> build.js:860
-----------------------------------------------------------------
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$vuetify.breakpoint is undefined"

found in

---> <FileBrowser> at node_modules/vuetify-file-browser/src/FileBrowser.vue
       <FileBrowser> at src/components/FileBrowser.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
-------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: this.$vuetify.breakpoint is undefined
    mounted FileBrowser.vue:219
    VueJS 14
    <anonymous> main.js:8
    js build.js:8912
    __webpack_require__ build.js:790
    fn build.js:101
    0 build.js:8937
    __webpack_require__ build.js:790
    <anonymous> build.js:857
    <anonymous> build.js:860
```

**FileBrowser.vue**

```
<template>
    <file-browser :axiosConfig="{baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081'}" />
</template>

<script>
import FileBrowser from "vuetify-file-browser";


export default {
    components: {
        FileBrowser
    }
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
}).$mount('#app')

// new Vue({
//   el: '#app',
//   render: h => h(App)
// }).$mount('#app');
```

**index.js (router component)**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import FileBrowser from '../components/FileBrowser.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'FileBrowser',
      component: FileBrowser
    }
  ]
})
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/main.js'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },

      // {
      //   test: /\.scss$/,
      //   use: [
      //     'vue-style-loader',
      //     'css-loader',
      //     'sass-loader'
      //   ],
      // },
      // {
      //   test: /\.sass$/,
      //   use: [
      //     'vue-style-loader',
      //     'css-loader',
      //     'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
      //   ],
      // },


      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              fiber: require('fibers'),
             // indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
            // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                fiber: require('fibers'),
               // indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },


      {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  


  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new ESLintPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vuetify-file-browser-app",
  "description": "frontend using Vue v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Alpug",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: No test has been specified, view scripts in package.json\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --open --hot"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-loader-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.4",
    "vuetify-file-browser": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Please remember I am new to Vuejs and anything wrong here, related to the error or otherwise, I would appreciate pointers on. Thank you for your time to read.

Comment: Use Vue CLI to generate project much easier and simple.

Comment: I did generate my project using the CLI tool, the issue lies with my sass parser I believe. If there is a specific command I can run for the CLI which would help I will, but could you elaborate? I already use the CLI

Comment: did you follow instruction in https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui

Comment: Yes, I have even created an entirely new project created with Vue and Typescript and the issue is identical in both projects despite totally different config

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-file-browser-server package is for nodejs backend. it won't work in frontend. have you looked at the package documentation. it doesn't say anywhere that you can use it as component but you are using it as component.

Comment: There is the vuetify-file-browser package, I know there is also a server package. This is the demo server for the component I'm talking about. This is clear in my package.json above, as you can see I have vuetify-file-browser. I have the server installed and running to use a mock data

Comment: https://github.com/semeniuk/vuetify-file-browser

Comment: I can confirm that this component works beautifully in my new vuejs project using vue 2, the issue was largely down to configuration, but it functions exactly as I expected it to @ToufiqAhmed